# Random input HIGH detect on GPIO

Tags: gpio

Trying to setup my door bell using raspberry PI B+, the input from the door bell stays at 0 DC and turns to 2.9v when the switch is pressed, I'm using the following python code to detect this activity

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.set(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        if (GPIO.input(13)==GPIO.HIGH:
            print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit()
```

the problem i'm getting is that even no one press the doorbell switch, randomly, around once per 10~20seconds, my Pi detects a GPIO.HIGH, thus, my doorbell project failed :-(

Any ideas?

PS: I used my multimeter to make sure my input is correct from doorbell, it read 0~0.01 in a steady 5 mins, while my Pi still gives me random GPIO.HIGH reads every 10~20 seconds in the same period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interference? Perhaps the long wires are bringing up noise beyond the ability of the internal pull-down resistor to suppress. Try something like a 5-10k external resistor pull-down on the GPIO.

Comment: Indeed. Break the problem down to debug it: disconnect the cable from the Pi, see if it still happens.

Comment: if i disconnect the cable,  it stays at low, Pi triggers the GPIO.HIGH only if I connect that two wires from the doorbell, but the multimeter always reads 0 from the doorbell wire

Comment: I will add a 5k resistor to see what happen tomorrow, tks for the quick reply Joan